# Knockout custom binding where is my binding?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/urajim/6/edit)

why dont this binding works. If i change the name of the observable in the Fields "class" to name instead of myName and in the binding to name:name it works. Dont understand this?

There should be 1 and 2 displayd in the boxes. Not a big number. And I want the property on my viewModel to be named myName. Something change the viewModel so in the template I have the Field binding istead of whats bound to the myBindings. I try to transfer that to the template

UPDATE
[NEW DEMO](http://jsbin.com/urajim/15/edit)
This is a much smaller example where you can see that the binding is the control1 and not the binding that I tought I was transfering to the template.

Comment: I ran your demo in Chrome and it works fine, what browser are you running?

Comment: can you please out some comments on your code

Comment: The demo works but not when you do the change i suggest.

Comment: Sorry the demo don't work. It not disply 1 and 2 in the boxes. I get a big number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is the real problem but i tried to inspect the data that you are passing to the template(just show the `$data` on click of the span). and i get that data passed to that template or it's view model is actually `Field` object that you get from the `foreach` binding.

So what you need to do is to change your the `databind` for the `span` inside your template into this:

```
<span data-bind="text:$data.myName"></span>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LqfXk/1/)**

**Update**

i think you get the data as `Field` object because your executing your custom binding inside of a `foreach`. From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html):

> The foreach binding duplicates a section of markup for each entry in
>   an array, ***and binds each copy of that markup to the corresponding
>   array item***.

Comment: There must be a way around this. So I dont have to have those exact properties on every viewmodel i bind to this.
There must be another way to do it then.